# Unity admob - Resolving Android Dependencies error

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Сломал всю голову. Импортирую ADMOB, потом пытаюсь установить библиотеки через - Resolving  Android Dependencie
И возникает ошибка:

C:\Users\Aleksandr\Desktop\Unity games\BubblesBumbes\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\gradlew.bat --no-daemon -b "C:\Users\Aleksandr\Desktop\Unity games\BubblesBumbes\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\PlayServicesResolver.scripts.download_artifacts.gradle" "-PANDROID_HOME=E:/Unity/Unity_app/2020.3.5f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer\SDK" "-PTARGET_DIR=C:\Users\Aleksandr\Desktop\Unity games\BubblesBumbes\Assets\Plugins\Android" "-PMAVEN_REPOS=https://maven.google.com/" "-PPACKAGES_TO_COPY=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.2.0" "-PUSE_JETIFIER=0" "-PDATA_BINDING_VERSION=3.6.0"
Executing command: C:\Users\Aleksandr\Desktop\Unity games\BubblesBumbes\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\gradlew.bat --no-daemon -b "C:\Users\Aleksandr\Desktop\Unity games\BubblesBumbes\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\PlayServicesResolver.scripts.download_artifacts.gradle" "-PANDROID_HOME=E:/Unity/Unity_app/2020.3.5f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer\SDK" "-PTARGET_DIR=C:\Users\Aleksandr\Desktop\Unity games\BubblesBumbes\Assets\Plugins\Android" "-PMAVEN_REPOS=https://maven.google.com/" "-PPACKAGES_TO_COPY=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.2.0" "-PUSE_JETIFIER=0" "-PDATA_BINDING_VERSION=3.6.0"

Reporting analytics data: /androidresolver/resolve/gradle/failed/fetch?unityVersion=2020.3.5f1&unityPlatform=WindowsEditor&installSource=unitypackage&version=1.2.167&scope= 'Android Resolver: Gradle Resolve: Tool Extraction Failed'
ERROR: Gradle failed to fetch dependencies.

Failed to run 'C:\Users\Aleksandr\Desktop\Unity games\BubblesBumbes\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\gradlew.bat --no-daemon -b "C:\Users\Aleksandr\Desktop\Unity games\BubblesBumbes\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\PlayServicesResolver.scripts.download_artifacts.gradle" "-PANDROID_HOME=E:/Unity/Unity_app/2020.3.5f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer\SDK" "-PTARGET_DIR=C:\Users\Aleksandr\Desktop\Unity games\BubblesBumbes\Assets\Plugins\Android" "-PMAVEN_REPOS=https://maven.google.com/" "-PPACKAGES_TO_COPY=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.2.0" "-PUSE_JETIFIER=0" "-PDATA_BINDING_VERSION=3.6.0"'
stdout:

stderr:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Gradle distribution 'C:\Users\Aleksandr.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.1.1-bin\90y9l8txxfw1s2o6ctiqeruwn' contains too many directories. Expected to find exactly 1 directory.

Прогуглил все что можно.. Что только не делал..
НУжна помощь !!!!

Comment: Никто не сталкивался с такой проблемой ?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, это может быть из-за гугл плей сервисов

Comment: автор вопроса написал в (уже удалённом модератором) ответе: «С проблемой разобрался ! Отбой !»